# Change the default terminal for all .desktop files?

Tags: terminal, mime-types

My `htop.desktop` launches XTerm, but I want to change the default terminal to xfce4-terminal in all "Terminal=true" .desktop files.

Comment: Which desktop are you using? Is it xfce? Which distro?

Comment: sorry, Arch Linux and Openbox in a x86_64 system

Comment: hmmm, on debian I'd have suggested to try `update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`. Maybe setting `$TERM` in `~/.profile` will do the trick?

Comment: Don't work the $TERM trick

Comment: Never set the $TERM in your shell initialization files; it has unintended and unpleasant side-affects...

Comment: I was looking for the same thing but sadly did not find any helpful info. Even browsing through the [specs](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html#introduction) did not reveal anything.

Answer (score 1):

Under the main (little mousy) menu, there is a "Settings" entry.

In there there is a "Default Applications" entry -- that's where you can change the default terminal emulator, the default browser, and the file-manager.

The dialog will present choices it deems suitable for each -- so be sure to have the desired application installed and present in the `$PATH` before looking for it there.